# Docker Container is not accessible from host machine

Tags: docker

I have my docker container running at local machine, here are the logs

```
{"level":30,"time":1686027701228,"pid":87,"msg":"server listening on http://127.0.0.1:53007"}
```

And also I have published the port.

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                     NAMES
415e84634ddd   axis      "pm2-runtime ./ecosy…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:8081->53007/tcp   axis
```

But still the application is not accessible from 0.0.0.0:8081

and it is part of `bridge` network (I didn't set it up explicitly, but got added by default)

```
"IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
        "Containers": {
            "415e84634ddd6c99bb275c9357a7c9841c7c2b4d675d80c52dc720b02a3d55b6": {
                "Name": "axis",
                "EndpointID": "e35895420ebe2efe7dd9b721891af53c7b190df69cfe893960f2438a012dcaa1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

I tried with many ip address combinations to access the docker container like
localhost, 127.0.0.1,

Comment: Did you try `127.0.0.1:8081` instead from the host machine?

Comment: Try running the application inside the docker container to listen to all interfaces i.e. `0.0.0.0` and not just the loopback address. Also try to make sure that the application is running inside of the container by **exec**uting a curl command.

Comment: Yes I tried @AndyRay, still not accessible

Comment: @Vishnupriya How did you test? with ping/telnet/curl? Is there a proxy in the host machine?

Comment: Thanks @PratikThakare It worked after changing ip to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score -1):

It worked after changing the ip to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Which IP?  Where did you change it?

Comment: I am using fastify framework in node js application. Those are listening at port 127.0.0.1:53007, now I have updated to 0.0.0.0:53007
Now the docker is accessible from localhost

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).